# Why PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser won't find an element?

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I'm using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser with following code snippet:

```
<?php
include_once('../simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://old.wowhead.com/npc=8404');

if ( $html->find('div.pin'))
echo 'Found';

?>
```

But it simply does not find

```
'<div class="pin" style="left: 17.7%; top: 60.8%; "><a href="javascript:;"     style="cursor: default; "></a></div>'
```

element on this html page: http://old.wowhead.com/npc=8404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `div` elements with class `pin` appears by JavaScript, so when you just download static html file there is no such elements.

Comment: Correct. If you disable JavaScript, the page displays nothing else than a warning: *This site makes extensive use of JavaScript.
Please enable JavaScript in your browser.*

Comment: Is there any way I could parse this then, if its shown by JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

i opened the link you gave and there is no div with a class of 'pin'. You have to give the method a valid element object.

try changing the selector to say

```
$html->find('div.pad1');
```

it works...in my case

Comment: anything, the element you are finding in the code is not in the dom. and also make it pad2 to see it work `$html->find('div.pad2');`

Comment: In my situation I user $html->find('div.pad2'); instead of $html->find('div .pad2'); so I got rid of the error. The space in between is very important to note